# is.vector(x) is not true

Tags: r, mapping, correlation, spatial

I'm performing a spatial econometric analysis on r. My database includes 78 countries, but as I need to match the column "code" of my database with that of the map (worldmap package of r), I had to include all countries and write NAs where I had no data.

```
# A tibble: 241 x 12
   code  country sales2010      gdp  gdppc population   Export   Import tradecost skills
   <chr> <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ABW   Aruba          NA NA          NA          NA NA       NA           NA     NA   
 2 AFG   Afghan…        NA NA          NA          NA NA       NA           NA     NA   
 3 AGO   Angola         NA NA          NA          NA NA       NA           NA     NA   
 4 AIA   Anguil…        NA NA          NA          NA NA       NA           NA     NA   
 5 ALB   Albania        NA NA          NA          NA NA       NA           NA     NA   
 6 ALD   Aland          NA NA          NA          NA NA       NA           NA     NA   
 7 AND   Andorra        NA NA          NA          NA NA       NA           NA     NA   
 8 ARE   United…        NA NA          NA          NA NA       NA           NA     NA   
 9 ARG   Argent…     44287  4.24e11 10386.   40788453  8.11e10  6.88e10      2.83   9.48
10 ARM   Armenia         4  9.26e 9  3218.    2877319  2.21e 9  4.54e 9      1.37  10.9 
# … with 231 more rows, and 2 more variables: investmentcost <dbl>, distance <dbl>
```

However, this is giving me many problems. I created a weighting matrix using the command zero.policy=TRUE to account for countries without neighbors and using na.omit() I managed to perform the moran test. However, when I run the moran.plot command it returns the error that na.omit(database$sales2010) is not a vector.

```
> moran.test(na.omit(database$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy=TRUE)

   Moran I test under randomisation

data:  na.omit(database$sales2010)  
weights: PPV3.w 
omitted: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 19, 21, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 34, 35, 36, 38, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 59, 60, 61, 63, 64, 66, 69, 71, 72, 74, 75, 78, 79, 81, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90, 91, 92, 98, 100, 101, 103, 105, 109, 112, 113, 115, 116, 117, 118, 120, 122, 123, 126, 127, 128, 129, 133, 134, 136, 137, 138, 139, 141, 142, 143, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 164, 165, 167, 168, 170, 173, 174, 176, 177, 180, 181, 182, 183, 185, 186, 189, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 215, 216, 217, 218, 220, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 232, 233, 235, 236, 237, 240 n reduced by no-neighbour observations


Moran I statistic standard deviate = 2.205, p-value = 0.01373
alternative hypothesis: greater
sample estimates:
Moran I statistic       Expectation          Variance 
      0.25571193       -0.01612903        0.01519935 

> ### Moran diagram
> moran.plot(na.omit(database$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE)
Error in moran.plot(na.omit(database$sales2010), PPV3.w,  : 
 is.vector(x) is not TRUE
```

This is how na.omit(database$sales2010) looks like:

```
[1]  44287      4 185329  20222   2019 130775   1123   6584     38    994 187351    312 600161 275761  32645 303281   1275   1642
[19]  24004   1781  18636 363995   5960  14952 100793    446  10643 211677    556 658153   1159      2   4762   5057    556    291
[37]  19039  34144  65621 271794    209  18539 131316    987    756 303618    658 107154   6531   1537   4311    316  28923    209
[55]   1955 227473   1411    469  57286 242155  51486  13592  10907  13722  21190  40124  13935   1790  41474  26593      1    152
[73]  32332  57996   7505  40122  23803   3069    940  36411    168
attr(,"na.action")
 [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8  11  12  13  14  15  19  21  22  23  25  27  28  30  31  34  35  36  38  44  46  47  49  50  51
[33]  52  53  54  55  59  60  61  63  64  66  69  71  72  74  75  78  79  81  83  84  85  86  87  89  90  91  92  98 100 101 103 105
[65] 109 112 113 115 116 117 118 120 122 123 126 127 128 129 133 134 136 137 138 139 141 142 143 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 155
[97] 156 157 158 159 160 161 164 165 167 168 170 173 174 176 177 180 181 182 183 185 186 189 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200
[129] 201 202 203 204 205 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 215 216 217 218 220 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 232 233 235 236 237 240
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

If I use a database where I already have excldued the NAs it returns that the x is not of the same lenght as the weight matrix.
How should I over come this problem?

Thank you

Comment: The example is not complete, so I can only speculate: One possible reason can be that `tibble` is not perfectly compatible to a standard `data.frame`. Not all R packages can work with such `tibble`s, but sometimes it helps to convert it back: `database <- as.data.frame(database)`

Comment: Have you tried `moran.plot(as.vector(na.omit(database$sales2010)), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that `moran.plot` requires `is.vector` is perhaps unnecessary, there are other ways to deal with it. Having said that, you need to do something other than `na.omit` to deal with missing values.

```r
is.vector(na.omit(1))
# [1] TRUE
na.omit(1)
# [1] 1

is.vector(na.omit(c(1,NA)))
# [1] FALSE
na.omit(c(1,NA))
# [1] 1
# attr(,"na.action")
# [1] 2
# attr(,"class")
# [1] "omit"
```

Perhaps

```r
my.na.omit <- function(z) z[!is.na(z)]
is.vector(my.na.omit(1))
# [1] TRUE
is.vector(my.na.omit(c(1,NA)))
# [1] TRUE
my.na.omit(c(1,NA))
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! However no it returns: Error in moran.plot(my.na.omit(database$sales2010), PPV3.w, zero.policy = TRUE) : 
  objects of different length. Do you know how can I overcome this?

Comment: I don't know your data or your `PPV3.w`, but if I had to guess, you should probably clean out the `NA`s *before* creating `PPV3.w` and/or otherwise make sure that it reflects the reduced data.

Comment: Perhaps instead of using `my.na.omit`, you should use `moran.plot(..., na.action=na.omit)`, as the presence of `na.action` suggests that `moran.plot` will deal with the length-inequity internally.

Comment: It returns: 
Error in moran.plot((database$sales2010), na.action = na.omit, PPV3.w,  : 
  NA in X

Comment: I don't know, without seeing the data that could be a bug in `moran.plot` or several other things. Does `?moran.plot` have anything more to say about `na.action`?

Comment: How can I show you my data? No it just returns the NA message

Comment: CamillaPanel96 ... I don't know how to help you! I have no idea how you created your weights ... my guess (as I said before) is that you need to remove missing data *before* creating your weights. (I confess that I don't have `spdep` installed, so this is all on speculation and reading the docs for it.)

Comment: Thank you very much anyway you have been very helpful!